# Put some button on image for explain something

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw a picture in the excel learn website . there was some buttons to explain excel buttons.
when click on the picture , menu open and explain that button

[please click to see page](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2016/getting-started-with-excel/1/)

Can anyone help me make one like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example for putting button over an image

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_on_image.asp

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please avoid link-only answers as they lose all value should the offsite resource change or disappear.  While including the link is fine, please also include the salient details in the answer body as well.  Thanks, and happy coding!